# Return to menu language GO

Tags: menu, go

I have a menu option with two options: add and substract. When I choose one it runs ok but the program closes. I would like to know how to make it go back to the menu after an operation ends to select another one

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var n1, n2, s, r float64
    var op, ns int

    fmt.Println("\n\tWelcome")
    fmt.Println("Chose an option")
    fmt.Println("1.-Add")
    fmt.Println("2.-Substract")
    fmt.Scan(&op)

    if op == 1 {

        fmt.Printf("\n\tAdd")
        fmt.Printf("\nHow many numbers you add? ")
        fmt.Scan(&ns)
        if ns <= 1 {
            fmt.Print("You can not add just a number")

        } else {
            for i := 0; i < ns; i++ {
                fmt.Printf("\nType the number %d: ", i+1)
                fmt.Scan(&n1)
                s += n1
            }

            fmt.Println("\nThe sum is: ", s)
            //How to return to the menu?
        }

    } else if op == 2 {
        fmt.Printf("\n\tSubtraction")
        fmt.Printf("\nType the first number: ")
        fmt.Scan(&n1)
        fmt.Printf("\nType the second number: ")
        fmt.Scan(&n2)
        r = n1 - n2
        fmt.Println("\nSubstraction is: ", r)
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your code (inc. your attempt at making this work)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just wrap the whole thing in

```
for {

}
```

Use `break` to exit the loop or `continue` to go back to the top.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell exactly without seeing your code, but I may assume you should use operator `for ;; {}` and put inside your menu with the appropriate `if/else` statements.